# jQuery Countdown until server's midnight time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use Keith Wood jQuery Countdown (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and call it like this:

```
var midnight = new Date(2020, 4-1, 29, 23, 59, 59);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown(
{
until: midnight, 
format: 'HMS', 
padZeroes: true, 
compact: true
});
```

There is no problem taking the midnight time on the client side, but how to get the midnight from the server? I tried it like this but no success:

```
var midnight = '<?= date("Y, n, j, G, i, s", strtotime('tomorrow')); ?>'
```

I'll be grateful for any ideas!

Comment: You would have to use AJAX to get the time from the server.

Comment: "I tried it like this but no success"...why, what wrong wrong exactly? It's unclear.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, the question is in the right date/time format, not in its source :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown(
{
until: +<?= strtotime('tomorrow') - time() ?>,
format: 'HMS', 
padZeroes: true, 
compact: true
});
```